# Does $AX+XB=B$ have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, nilpotence

Let $A, B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ such that $A$ is nilpotent but $B$ is non-nilpotent satisfying $AB+BA=O$. Then, $AX+XB=B$ has unique solution. True or false?

---

I don't understand how to approach this problem. Any hint, please?

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem, like a textbook or a PDF? Kindly ensure that you edit your source and any references that you have studied from (textbooks etc.) so that others may freely use results from them (and to confirm, if necessary, that this is not from an ongoing exam).

Comment: Note that "non-nilpotent" is a really weak condition on $B$, so I'd start looking for a counterexample.  In particular, note that $A=O$ is nilpotent and satisfies $AB+BA=O$ for any $B$.  Now try to choose $B$ so that $BX=B$ doesn't have a unique solution.